# How to get the google map and facebook working for the release apk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, sha1

I have done integration of both Facebook login and google map(including the google map place picker) and those are working really very fine.

Now i have to make the release version , I have read all over the internet but I am not getting the map working as it shows the blank page and Place picker disappears when it get pop up , Also facebook is giving me key hash error.

So I am posting my question here , so that some one tell me how to do things in step by step procedural way ,with a easy wordings not eh words used by official document As I am so dumb to understand them

I request you , please help me in making the release version of my app. every thing is working fine in the debug version.

Please help me in both facebook and google Map cases.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook required two type of hash key. One is Debug hash key, and another is release hash key.

Use this method to print hash key.

When you debug your apk, It give a hash key, but when you run your release apk in your device.. it return different hash key. add both key at facebook developer console..

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "Your package name", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Your Tag", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

code to generate sha key programmatically.

```
PackageInfo info;
try {

    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "com.example.worldmission", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        Log.e("Hash key", something);
        System.out.println("Hash key" + something);
    }

} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: how can I get the release hash key from device

Comment: Connect your device to your Android studio. Run app by pressing app from Home screen. It will print hashkey in log cat.

Comment: but in this way , isnt it the debud has key ?

Comment: How I would get the release hash key ?

Comment: If you run your app from android studio.. then it will give debug key my dear. I told you to run app from your device. and collect log from android studio

Comment: If you are having problem in this. then Print that has key as a form of textview. and then write on facebook developer manually

Comment: I have tried it , but its not printing it in log :(

Comment: Ok.. Do one thing. call this method from any of your activity, and print log in any textview.

Comment: ok, But Run your app from home screen of your device.. not from android studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107547/discussion-between-allay-khalil-and-himanshu-shekher-jha).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at these :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

and after that;

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

So you can find a way after read this docs.

Comment: can you please explain it , I have seen videos they are using the open ssl way to get the release key ?